# Is there an efficient way to calculate k so that x^k % m = 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm toying with modular exponentiation. Not being a mathematician, I could still figure that `x^y % m` is equivalent to `x^(y%k) % m` where `k` is such that `x^k % m = 1`.

Well, I think.

I can't prove anything formally, because I don't have enough knowledge or mathematical tools in my belt, but here's a try:

```
x^y % m =  x^(y%k + nk) % m
x^y % m = (x^(y%k) . x^nk) % m
x^y % m = (x^(y%k) . (x^k)^n) % m
x^y % m = (x^(y%k) . (x^k % m)^n) % m
x^y % m = (x^(y%k) . 1^n) % m   // by definition of k
x^y % m = (x^(y%k) . 1) % m
x^y % m =  x^(y%k) % m
```

I'll let to you the delight to prove that better, or find a proof somewhere, or disprove it.

modular exponentiation could be simplified if there were a shortcut to calculate `k`. Does that exist ? Is it a known problem ? Has the "simplification"'s efficiency been proven or disproved yet ?

Comment: There is a huge literature on this. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) for a gentle introduction. Your $k$ is Euler's phi function $\varphi(m)$.

Comment: "The difficulty of computing `phi(n)` without knowing the factorization of n is thus the difficulty of computing d (the private key) this is known as the RSA problem" (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function). So... yeah.